# Complex power series expansion of $\frac{e^z}{1+z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I'm trying to find complex power series expansion of $\frac{e^z}{1+z}$ centered at $z=0$ and its radius of convergence. Here is my attempt:

Since $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$, we can divide both terms by $1+z$ to get $e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{(1+z)n!}$. Then I can get radius of convergence using the usual Cauchy-Hadamard formula.

Is this correct?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What you obatin is *not* a power series expansion since there's a $z$ in the denominators.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/521894/complex-power-series-expansion-for-fz-fraceza-z for a correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

In order to get the power series expansion we could multiply the series $e^z$ with $\frac{1}{1+z}$ using the *[Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)*

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{e^z}{1+z}&=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}\right)\left(\sum_{l=0}^\infty (-z)^l\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{{k+l=n}\atop{k,l\geq 0}}\frac{(-1)^l}{k!}\right)z^n\tag{2}\\
> &=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{k!}\right)z^n
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we use the series expansion for the exponential function and the *[geometric series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*
- In (2) we multiply the series using the Cauchy product formula

> We observe the function
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1+z}
> \end{align*}
>   has a simple pole at $z=-1$. We also know that the exponential function is an *[entire function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entire_function)*, i.e. analytic in $\mathbb{C}$. Since the radius of convergence is the distance from the center $z=0$ to the nearest singularity, we conclude the radius is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

As said, it is false, you need to obtain something like $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n.$$
To answer the question, remark that for $|z|<1$ we have $$\frac{1}{1+z} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-1)^n z^n$$ and of course $$e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{z^n}{n!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Gather the like powers
$$
   \left(1+\frac{1}{1!}z+\frac{1}{2!}z^2+\frac{1}{3!}z^3+\cdots\right)(1-z+z^2-z^3+\cdots) \\
   =1+(-1+\frac{1}{1!})z+(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!})z^2+(-1+\frac{1}{1!}-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!})z^3+\cdots
$$
The resulting series is guaranteed to converge in $|z| < 1$ because the first two series converge absolutely in that disk. It can't converge in a disk of radius $r > 1$ because that disk includes the singularity of $\frac{1}{1+z}$ at $z=-1$.